# Shopware: Unable to connect with STARTTLS without encryption

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, symfony-mailer

In my .env file I have:

> MAILER_URL="smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="

But if I send a mail the log shows:

> Could not send mail: Failed sending mail to following recipients: {{ recipients }} with Error: Unable to connect with STARTTLS. Error Code:0 Template data ...

Looks like it tries to use TLS but I don't want to. It worked before. Maybe it got broken by an update.

Looking at the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#encryption) I also tried `encryption=null` with same result.

Debugging in `vendor/shopware/core/Content/Mail/Service/MailerTransportFactory.php:36` I made sure my `MAILER_URL` was used.

I am using shopware 6.4.1.1 with symfony/mailer v5.2.10

How can I get mails working again?

Comment: Have you tried to set the parameter `verify_peer=0` (see the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification)).

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the SMTP transport in the Symfony Mailer performs TLS peer verification. You can disable this verification by setting the parameter [`verify_peer`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification) to `0`, for example:

```
MAILER_URL="smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode=&verify_peer=0"
```

Comment: I got some additional information: Symfony Mailer removed the parameters `encryption` and `auth_mode`. If you like to use TLS you should use `smtps://`. Also if the server supports TLS it automatically uses it, even if you did not select `smtps://`. I my case the certificate was self signed, that is why the `verify_peer=0` is needed. All in all this will do the same: `MAILER_URL="smtp://localhost:25?verify_peer=0"`

Comment: See also: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/41997